# how to handle the Windows Form got focus event in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have Windows Form.Now i want to perform some function when the form get focused(that was already opened).For example,form has already opened, and user minimized that window and perform some other function.Finally, he will maximize that form to doing function.So, on that time, i want to perform function(while getting focused to the user). how i do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the Form's [`Activated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx) event.

EDIT:

This is the code I tried

```
public Form1()
{
    this.Activated += new EventHandler(Form1_Activated);
}

void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Activated");
}
```

Comment: @Bala R : there is no such event in form

Comment: @Saravanan sorry, can you check `Activated` event?

Comment: @Bala R:One Doubt here... Is this fulfil my request?i think Activated and got focus are different things...what u think?

Comment: @Saravanan From MSDN for `Activated` `"Occurs when the form is activated in code or by the user."`. I'm pretty sure it this event will work for you.

Comment: @Saravanan I just tested it and it works every time the form is restored. The only thing is it also fires the first time the form comes up. I'm not sure if that's something that you want or not. That can be avoided with a simple flag, I would reckon.

Comment: @Bala :It is not working... first i minimized my form.then maximize the same form, it did not work...

Comment: @Saravanan I have included the code that I tried and It is working for me when I minimize and the restore the form later.